# How to store MIniProfiler data using Console application

Tags: c#, console-application, mvc-mini-profiler

I have implement one console application and added Miniprofiler to this application.

Now I want to store Miniprofiler data to database. I have execute the script to create tables to database. You can find script [here](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/blob/85609b6226eff71ac21dfa990dd1fa54aace237f/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/SqlServerStorage.cs#L511)!

I have reviewed answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695460/how-to-store-mvc-miniprofiler-results)

But How can I store the profiler values to related tables?

In MVC below line is used to store values:

```
MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage = new SqlServerStorage("<your connection string>");
```

How can I store these values from the Console application?

Comment: Right now I am writing them to one text file. But I want to store all values in Database

Comment: I have reviewed this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695460/how-to-store-mvc-miniprofiler-results

Comment: hmmm, actually it looks like you *should* just need to use `MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage.Save(profiler);`; have you tried that? That should populate `MiniProfilers` and `MiniProfilerTimings`.

Comment: When I add this, it need reference for Miniprofiler.Settings and through this error :  The type or namespace name 'Settings' does not exist in the namespace 'MiniProfiler' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above works fully, and records the expected data to the `MiniProfilers` and `MiniProfilerTimings` tables. The key bits in the setup code are:

- specifying a storage provider (you already had this)
- specifying a profiler provider (singleton in my case)
- start/stop the profiler around the work
- save the profiler after the work

Code:

```
using StackExchange.Profiling;
using StackExchange.Profiling.Storage;
using System;
using System.Threading;
//using StackExchange.Profiling.Helpers.Dapper; // only for table creation
//using System.Data.SqlClient; // only for table creation

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const string ConnectionString = "Initial Catalog=MiniProf;Data Source=.;Integrated Security=true;";

        //using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        //{
        //    conn.Open();
        //    conn.Execute(SqlServerStorage.TableCreationScript);
        //}
        MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage = new SqlServerStorage(ConnectionString);
        MiniProfiler.Settings.ProfilerProvider = new SingletonProfilerProvider();
        MiniProfiler.Settings.ProfilerProvider.Start(ProfileLevel.Info);
        DoStuff();
        MiniProfiler.Settings.ProfilerProvider.Stop(false);

        MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage.Save(MiniProfiler.Current);
    }
    static void DoStuff()
    {
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("DoStuff"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Loop iteration"))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    Console.Write(".");
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. But as I told you before When I write   MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage = new SqlServerStorage(ConnectionString); it throws an error : The type or namespace name 'Settings' does not exist in the namespace 'MiniProfiler' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Can you please advice what need to do for this reference?

Comment: @Ankita the code above is using miniprofiler 3.1.1.140 from nuget, and compiles. What version are you using?

Comment: Same version of miniprofiler 3.1.1.140  Do I need to add some DLL for this?

Comment: ah, do you perhaps have your own class called `MiniProfiler` somewhere?

Comment: meaning: if you click on `MiniProfiler` on the offending line, and press `F12` - does it show you the breakdown from `Assembly MiniProfiler, Version=3.1.1.140, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3`?

Comment: No, I have added Reference of Miniprofiler. There is not any method named "MiniProfiler".

Comment: @Ankita are you sure you aren't seeing "The type 'System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'." ?

Comment: because if I create a new 4.5 console exe, run `install-package MiniProfiler`, past the code above; that is the only problem I get. That has an auto-fix suggested by the IDE that *does exactly that*; after that: it compiles

Comment: Okay..I have added this line :    StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage = new SqlServerStorage(_connectionString); and it works.

Comment: Did you have the `using StackExchange.Profiling;` line that I included at the top of my answer? the very first line?

Comment: I have also added this reference but do not know why it need that. Moreover now it throws this error : Invalid column name 'CustomLinksJson'.

Invalid column name 'ClientTimingsRedirectCount'. from this line  StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage.Save(StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.Current);

Comment: @Ankita the correct table creation script can be found at `SqlServerStorage.TableCreationScript`. If you ran anything else, it could be an old version.

Comment: @Ankita re the rest; I strongly suspect that you have a type, property or namespace in your project called MiniProfiler that is confusing the name resolution. I would advise: don't do that.

Comment: Have you run the same script which I have mentioned in my question? Else can you please give me the link?

Comment: @Ankita my answer **shows the exact code** I used to create the tables; it is **on the object model**, at `StackExchange.Profiling.Storage.SqlServerStorage.TableCreationScript`. And no, I didn't use the script from your link: why would I? The script to use is **in the object model**. And: your link is very very wrong: the correct link is https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/SqlServerStorage.cs#L380-L428

Comment: Can you please explain me about profiler provider?: "specifying a profiler provider (singleton in my case)"

Comment: @Ankita that just tells the system how `MiniProfiler.Current` should work. For example, on a web server, that probably means "look relative to the current http request". In your case, you presumably only *have* one thing going on, so it is probably OK if all calls to `MiniProfiler.Current` return the same thing; which is exactly what `MiniProfiler.Settings.ProfilerProvider = new SingletonProfilerProvider();` arranges

Comment: But it throws an error: The type or namespace name 'SingletonProfilerProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Ankita you do realize that you can just press `ctrl`+`.` in visual studio an *it will fix that for you*, yes? or right-click? or click on the yellow light bulb? The full namespace, if you want to do it manually, is `StackExchange.Profiling`; and the fully qualified type name is `StackExchange.Profiling.SingletonProfilerProvider`.

Comment: Thank You Marc, Now successfully insert the values into database.